# How to get list of imported packages and their versions in Julia 1.0?

Tags: julia

Ideally, I would like to get something equivalent of `SessionInfo()` in R, that lists the version of the R together with the list of all currently loaded libraries together with their versions.

I miss a similar functionality in Julia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Pkg should have what you need:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.status()
```

Or using the Julia 1.0.0 Package Manager, one could:

```
# Press the `]` key to access the package manager, then:
(v1.0) pkg> status
# Press backspace key to exit back to REPL.
```

Comment: Isn't `Pkg.status()` only giving you the version of the packages in the current environment?
What do you need to do to really see the packages that are already loaded, independent of the environment you are currently in?

Comment: This is not quite right, even though it's often what you want. Most dangerously, if any packages were imported before activating the environment (or before running `Pkg.update()`), the imported packages might have a different version than the one shown by this command . The only fix is to reload Julia AFAIK. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/32906.